# Not able to redirect page on selection from select drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I used a jquery plugin for select drop down menu with images,There i want to redirect the page to specific url provided in option value of select menu.But i m not able to redirect it.please guide me following is the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ddslick.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDropdown"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Dropdown plugin data
var ddData = [
    {
        text: "Facebook",
        value: "http://www.facebook.com",
        description: "Description with Facebook",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
    },
    {
        text: "Twitter",
        value: "http://www.google.com",
        description: "Description with Twitter",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
    },
    {
        text: "LinkedIn",
        value: 3,
        description: "Description with LinkedIn",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png"
    },
    {
        text: "Foursquare",
        value: 4,
        description: "Description with Foursquare",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png"
    }
];
//Code Ends
//Code Starts
$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
    data:ddData,
    width:300,
    selectText: "Select your preferred social network",
    imagePosition:"right",
    onSelected: function(selectedData){

    }   
});
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#myDropdown').change( function() {
      location.href = $(this).val();
   });
});


//Code Ends
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out in this..

Comment: try this 
`$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
    data:ddData,
    width:300,
    selectText: "Select your preferred social network",
    imagePosition:"right",
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
      location.href = $(this).val();
    }   
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ddslick plugin replaces your select element with other elements, to make the slick dropdown, so you can't use the original select's change event. Instead you should use the `onSelected` event of the plugin:

```
$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
    data:ddData,
    width:300,
    selectText: "Select your preferred social network",
    imagePosition:"right",
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        location.href = selectedData.selectedData.value;
    }   
});
```

Comment: Now when i select facebook.its appending the word undefined in the url,but i want it should go to facebook.com and append the same,Please tell me where i m doing wrong...

Comment: Try adding `console.log(selectedData)` in the function, to see what that contains. Press F12 to see the console.

Comment: in console.on selection of any option ,i am getting this error:-Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.

Comment: See my edit, you need to use `location.href = selectedData.selectedData.value;`.

Comment: ya.sir.it worked.can u please help me with the explanation of what u fixed in code sir..

Comment: It turns out the value is in selectedData.selectedData, so it's in selectedData within the data argument (a nested object).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/HaCTg/5/

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#myDropdown .dd-option').click( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      location.href = ($(this).children('.dd-option-value').val());
   });
});
```

Note that jsfiddle will not actually redirects you, but if you change:

```
location.href = ($(this).children('.dd-option-value').val());
```

into:

```
console.log($(this).children('.dd-option-value').val());
```

You will see that the code is working.